# How to hide icon from WPF window (Helix)

Tags: wpf, helix-3d-toolkit, helix

I'm using HelixToolkit to show some 3-D models. There is an icon in the right bottom of the window. How can it be hidden? Please look at  this screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You only have to set the `HelixViewport3D`'s `ShowViewCube` property to false:

```
<h:HelixViewport3D ShowViewCube="False">
    ...
<h:HelixViewport3D>
```

Comment: It would be good if this answer was marked as the accepted answer @Linojan - I see you are still active on StackOverflow, could you spare the time to do this?